# Emmet code structure for large one line code

Tags: emmet

How to get Emmet codding to get html structure from this code:

```
.header>.logo+.lang.+.menu+.container+.row>+.col-md-6+.col-md-6
```

I need to get `container` element outside of `header` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use grouping or climb-up syntax

#### Grouping: ()

`(.header>.logo+.lang.+.menu)+.container+.row>+.col-md-6+.col-md-6`

#### Climb-up: ^

`.header>.logo+.lang.+.menu^.container+.row>+.col-md-6+.col-md-6`

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="lang "></div>
    <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

See [Emmet Documentation: Abbreviation Syntax](http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/)

***Edit:*** *Answer updated to include climb-up syntax alternative*

Comment: Or `^^^` `.header>.logo+.lang.+.menu^^^.container+.row>+.col-md-6+.col-md-6`.http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/

Comment: The `^` will take you up one level, so in your case you only need one `^`: `.header>.logo+.lang.+.menu^.container+.row>+.col-md-6+.col-md-6` I'll add this to my answer as an alternative method.